# NSData access in iOS for external accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, photokit

I am trying to transfer the photo image data accessed from the Photos framework to my external accessory. I am able to transfer the data. However, I am not able to open the file correctly.

I access the data of the image using the NSData in the PHImagemanager. 
I am transferring the image to an external device (SD card using the External accessory protocol). The transfer takes place successfully. I can see the ASCII contents of the original file and the transferred file and they both look the same. But I cannot open the file.

I was thinking that do I have to do some processing on the data I receive through NSData to open the image successfully?

Comment: show code, please.

Comment: The code is in 5 different functions. It is not a small piece of code with few lines...

Comment: show the code where the file open fails.

Comment: The file does not open on the computer. It is not on iphone.

Comment: I doubt the way I am acquiring the data from iPhone. When you use the image manager, do you access the data using imageData or by using the URL in the info dictionary.

Comment: [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
     requestImageDataForAsset: asset
     options:imageRequestOptions
     resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                     UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info)

Comment: This is how I am trying to access the image. I am then using the imageData to get the data bytes of the image